# Is there any cyclic subgroup of order 6 in in $ S_6$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is there any cyclic subgroup of order 6 in   $ S_6$?

**Attempt:**

$|S_6|=6!=720$

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_6$ ,$H$ cyclic $\iff\langle H \rangle=\{e,h,h^2,...,h^{n-1}\}=S_6$

Comment: Any element of order $\;6\;$ generats such a subgroup, e.g. $\;\langle\,(123456)\,\rangle\;,\;\;\langle\,(12)(345)\,\rangle\;$ , etc.

Comment: Fact (Cayley's theorem) : Any group of order $n$ embeds into $S_n$.

Comment: @BalarkaSen How can I conclude this from Cayley's theorem?

Comment: @nehorairaphael $\Bbb Z_6$ is a group of order $6$. Thus, it embeds into $S_6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: no need of great theorems. The subgroup generated by $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ does the job.